# Android Contact cursor take too much time to iterate

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts, android-cursor

I want to fetch all contacts from Phone Contact app and insert into local sqlite db.
but problem is that the android contact cursor take time to iterate...

CODE:

```
private Cursor getContacts() {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                sortOrder);
    }
```

INSERT INTO DB:

```
long mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int batch = 50;

        try {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            // InsertHelper insertHelper = new InsertHelper(db,
            // TABLE_USER_INFO);
            // String insertSql =
            // "INSERT INTO UserInfo (firstname,lastname,userid,serveruserid,phonenumber,emailaddress,street,state,city,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
            // SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = db.compileStatement(insertSql);

            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount() / batch
                            + (((cursor.getCount() % batch) > 0) ? 1 : 0); i++) {
                        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        db.beginTransaction();

                        sqlBuilder
                                .append("INSERT INTO UserInfo (firstname,lastname,userid,serveruserid,phonenumber,emailaddress,street,state,city,country) ");

                        for (int j = 0; j < batch; j++) {

                            String name = cursor
                                    .getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            long _id = cursor
                                    .getLong(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                            // ADDRESS
                            Cursor address = context
                                    .getContentResolver()
                                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + _id, null, null);
                            String street = null, city = null, state = null, country = null;
                            while (address.moveToNext()) {
                                street = address
                                        .getString(address
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                                city = address
                                        .getString(address
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                                state = address
                                        .getString(address
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                                country = address
                                        .getString(address
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));

                            } // address.moveToNext()
                            address.close();

                            // PHONE NO
                            String phoneNumber = null;
                            Cursor phones = context
                                    .getContentResolver()
                                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + _id, null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                phoneNumber = phones
                                        .getString(phones
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            }
                            phones.close();

                            // EMAIL ID
                            String emailId = null;
                            Cursor emails = context
                                    .getContentResolver()
                                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + _id, null, null);
                            while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                                emailId = emails
                                        .getString(emails
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                            }
                            emails.close();

                            // INSERT INTO DB
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                            String[] names = name.split(" ");
                            if (name != null && names.length == 1) {
                                values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, name);
                                values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, "");
                            } else if (name != null && names.length > 1) {
                                values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, names[0]);
                                values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, names[1]);
                            }

                            // Log.d(TAG, "User Id:" + _id);

                            values.put(KEY_USER_LOCAL_ID, _id);
                            values.put(KEY_SERVER_USER_ID, "0");

                            if (phoneNumber != null
                                    && !phoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                // REPLACE "-" FROM PHONE NO
                                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "")
                                        .trim();
                                values.put(KEY_PH_NO, IOUtils
                                        .getFormatedPhoneNo(context,
                                                phoneNumber));
                                Log.e(TAG, "Inserting contacts into db name:"
                                        + name + " Phone:" + phoneNumber);
                            }

                            if (emailId != null)
                                values.put(KEY_EMIAL, emailId);

                            if (street != null)
                                values.put(KEY_STREET, street);
                            if (state != null)
                                values.put(KEY_STATE, state);
                            if (city != null)
                                values.put(KEY_CITY, city);
                            if (country != null)
                                values.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);

                            if (emailId == null && phoneNumber == null) {
                                // Log.d(TAG, "email,ph no not found:" + name);
                            } else {

                                Log.e(TAG, "*** Name:" + name + " Email id:"
                                        + emailId + " phone:" + phoneNumber);

                                if (j == 0)
                                    sqlBuilder.append(" SELECT ");
                                else
                                    sqlBuilder.append(" UNION SELECT ");

                                sqlBuilder
                                        .append("'"
                                                + values.getAsString(
                                                        KEY_FIRST_NAME)
                                                        .replace("'", "") + "'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_FIRST_NAME + ", ");
                                sqlBuilder.append(
                                        "'"
                                                + values.getAsString(
                                                        KEY_LAST_NAME).replace(
                                                        "'", "") + "'").append(
                                        " AS " + KEY_LAST_NAME + ", ");
                                sqlBuilder
                                        .append("'"
                                                + values.getAsString(KEY_USER_LOCAL_ID)
                                                + "'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_USER_LOCAL_ID
                                                + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_SERVER_USER_ID) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_SERVER_USER_ID)
                                                : " ")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_SERVER_USER_ID
                                                + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values.getAsString(KEY_PH_NO) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_PH_NO) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_PH_NO + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values.getAsString(KEY_EMIAL) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_EMIAL) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_EMIAL + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values.getAsString(KEY_STREET) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_STREET) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_STREET + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values.getAsString(KEY_STATE) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_STATE) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_STATE + ", ")
                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values.getAsString(KEY_CITY) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_CITY) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_CITY + ", ")

                                        //
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append((values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_COUNTRY) != null) ? values
                                                .getAsString(KEY_COUNTRY) : "")
                                        .append("'")
                                        .append(" AS " + KEY_COUNTRY);
                            }
                            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Cursor pos" + cursor.getPosition());
                                break;

                            }
                        }

                        // Log.d(TAG, "BUILDER: " + sqlBuilder.toString());
                        db.execSQL(sqlBuilder.toString());
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        db.endTransaction();
                        Log.e("Time:",
                                "operatio time"
                                        + (mStartTime - System
                                                .currentTimeMillis()));
                    }
                }
            }

            // CLOSE DB

            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // insertHelper.c
        }
```

it took 4 mins to insert....

Please suggest efficient way to iterate cursor.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us how you're doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

With a `managedQuery(...)` you can cast a query projection (in form of an array of columns you want to extract) and extract much larger data. By doing so you mitigate the problem of separate querying of the database. This is what takes the biggest tall at the process.

Plus there is the new `CursorLoader` class, present in support package v4, to load that data asynchronously.

Furthermore you can use `moveToNext()` to iterate with `while` loop since cursors always start "before" the data.